# How do I make Atom my default editor?

Tags: macos, default, atom-editor

Dreamweaver loads up every time I click on a HTML file I want to work on. It would be great if I could swap dreamweaver for atom as the default. I can't figure out how to do this. Currently on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 and Atom version Version 0.165.0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a detailed description of this here: http://www.macworld.com/article/1154861/changedefaultapp.html

The general steps:

- In Finder, right-click an HTML file
- From the context menu, select *Get Info*
- In the dialog that opens, there's an entry for "Open with", which should show DreamWeaver in your case
- Open the dropdown and select Atom - it should be one of the available options.
- Click the *Change All...* button and confirm the change in the popup.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!